# ui-grid how to get columns and headers to line up and span full width of the grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I've just started testing with ui-grid to see if I can use it in some of my projects. The problem I am having is when it renders the columns are of various sizes and do not line up with the column headers.

Within my controller I am defining the gridOptions as follows:

```
var vm = this;        
vm.smtGridOptions = {
            columnDefs:
            [{ field: 'smtTypeCodeText', displayName: 'Type' },
                { field: 'description', displayName: 'Description' },
                { field: 'location', displayName: 'Location' },
                { field: 'dateEntered', displayName: 'Date Entered' }
            ]
        }
```

the data is bound further down using

```
vm.smtGridOptions.data = vm.detail.smts;
```

In my html I have the grid added as follows:

```
<div ng-show="name.detail.smts.length > 0" scroll-to-section>
   [![enter image description here][1]][1]<hr style="clear: both; margin-bottom: 5px !important;"/>
      <a class="anchorOffset" id="smts"></a>
      <p>
        <strong><em>SMTs</em></strong>
     </p>
  <div id="smtGrid" ui-grid="name.smtGridOptions" class="uigrid"></div>
</div>
```

As a note, I'm using ui-router in this project so name represents the ControllerAs for the current view.

Options and data binding are working but when the application renders. I get a grid rendered like this:
[image: weird column sizing]

Is there a setting or CSS setting that will allow the grid columns to span (almost in a justified manner) the width of the grid. Currently it appears that it valuates the data in the grid and renders the column to match regardless of column definition.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I'm using ui-router and ui-bootstrap. My grids were in a uib-tab element from the ui-bootstrap project. When switching between tabs I was experiencing the rendering you're seeing.

What worked for me was injecting 'ui.grid.autoResize' into my module and adding the ui-grid-auto-resize directive to my grid div.

On the the ui-grid tutorial page here: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/108_hidden_grids There is a link to this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fwdXMamTBrR1yKVwcohZ?p=preview which has a similar setup that I followed.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.grid.autoResize']);

<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-auto-resize class="grid"></div>
```